# How to rotate text in a plotly trace?

Tags: python, plotly

The following trace displays some text in a plotly graph. I would like to rotate this text to 90°. I tried `textangle` keyword, but that does not work.

```
trace = go.Scatter(
    x=[1999],
    y=[1],
    mode='text',
    name='Note',
    text=['Missing data due to database change'],
    textposition='middle center'
)
```

Comment: Hi @Soren, did you manage to find a solution for this? I have the exact same challenge!

Answer (score 0):

Was having this issue today. That method works in R, but not sure about Python. Fortunately, there's more than 1 way to add text to plots. I managed to get it to work by using annotations instead...

```
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1) # instantiate fig
x, y = [1999], [1] # vars
# create scatter
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=y,
            mode='markers',
            name='Name',
        )
# create annotations iteratively for each var
for c, val in enumerate(x): ## count, val
    fig.add_annotation(
        x=x[c], 
        y =y[c],
        text=['text'],
        showarrow=False,
        align='center',
        textangle=-45,
        yanchor='bottom', 
        font=dict(color='rgb(255,0,0)', size=10))
        
fig.update_layout(
title_text="Title",
title_font_size=20,
font_size=16,
title_x=0.06,
showlegend=True,
legend_font_size=12,
height=600,
width=1200,
template='simple_white',
)

fig.show()
```

Learn more here: https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/